# Laravel Stripe Payment Error Redirect Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, stripe-payments

If the payment is successful, it redirects to the "success" page, but if the payment fails, it does not redirect to the "cancel" page, it looks like the photo below. I will be glad if you can help, thank you.

[image]

```
/* stripe code */ else if ($payment_method == 'stripe') {


            $stripe = array(
                "secret_key"      => $stripe_secret_key,
                "publishable_key" => $stripe_publish_key
            );

            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);


            $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
                'email' => $order_email,
                'source'  => $token
            ));


            $item_name = $item_names_data;
            $item_price = $amount * 100;
            $currency = $site_currency;
            $order_id = $purchase_token;

            try {
                
            $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
                'customer' => $customer->id,
                'amount'   => $item_price,
                'currency' => $currency,
                'description' => $item_name,
                'metadata' => array(
                    'order_id' => $order_id
                )
            ));


            $chargeResponse = $charge->jsonSerialize();

            
            if ($chargeResponse['paid'] == 1 && $chargeResponse['captured'] == 1) {



                return view('success')->with($data_record);
            }
            } catch (\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
              return view('cancel');
         }
                
       
        }
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple things unclear and it's hard to help you with just this information.

1. You are using Charge API which is an old and legacy API. It's
   better to go with [Payment Intent API](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web).
2. It looks like you haven't written a full error handling logic. You can debug by catching all possible Error types, including the ApiErrorException you are receiving. See example on [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php).